# recursive javascript no recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku

Im making a script that solves a 3*3 sudoku. these would be a working answers:

```
123   312
231   123
312   231
```

As an input, I would give a 3*3 sudoku, where the zeros are blank spots.
this one would work:
023
230
310

as an output, I would get:
123
231
312

However my script doesnt work.
My input is called sq
I have a function called findZero that searches for a zero
I have a function called fill that removes the zero for a working number
i have a function called checkRC (check row column) that scans for a working number

This would be a recursive script.

However, with this script I would get with the given input:

```
[0, 2, 3],
[2, 3, 0],
[3, 1, 0]
```

this output:

```
[1, 2, 3],
[2, 3, 0],
[3, 1, 0],
```

so it only changes it one time and then stops I think.
I have no clue how to repair this!

This is my code:

```
var sq = [
    [0, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [3, 1, 0]
];
var x;
var y;

function findZero(square) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (square[i][j] === 0) {
                x = i;
                y = j;
                return [x, y];
            }
        }
    }
    return [-1, -1];
}

function fill(square) {

    if (findZero(square)[0] == -1) {

        return square; }

      else {
        for (var w = 1; w < 4; w++) {
            if(checkRC(square,x,y,w) === true){
             square[x][y] = w;
                return square;


            }
        }
     }
}


var bool = true

 function checkRC(square, x, y, w) {

    for (var k = 0; k < 3&&bool; k++) {
        if (square[x][k] == w || square[k][y] == w) {
            bool = false;
            return bool;
          }
          else{
            bool = true;
            return bool;

        }
    }
}


console.log(fill(sq));
```

If you find a jsfiddle link easier:

http://jsfiddle.net/akqn7/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't have the chance to look at the code in details but I would recommend you to use backtracking in order to be able to solve wider range of sudokus.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Backtracking is a thing im trying to do, but im a beginner in programming!

Comment: Should the top row of the input be [0, 2, 3]?

Comment: Also your script doesn't seem to be recursive. You're going for an iterative solution. In the code you'd basically need to continue the loop until either there's no more zeros or there is no legitimate solution.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you never called your function in recursive !

```
function fill(square) {

    if (findZero(square) === null) {
        return square;
    } else {
        for (var w = 1; w < 4; w++) {
            if (checkRC(square, x, y, w) === true) {
                square[x][y] = w;
                return fill(square);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Look how i placed return fill(); that's where your recursive needs to be

Your function checkRC was wrong too, here's the corrected version:

```
function checkRC(square, x, y, w) {

    var bool = true;

    for (var k = 0; k < 3 && bool; k++) {
        if (square[x][k] == w || square[k][y] == w) {
            bool = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

I placed the bool inside the function and don't return directly the result because if it was false to the first number, it would stop.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akqn7/1/)

Comment: Also your function findZero seems to only return the value to know if there are still zeros, you could simply return true or false instead !

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for your answer. That really helped. I still need to make it so it can do backtracking. You have an idea?

Comment: I have done a sudoku in the past, and how I did it was create some "class", one for the grid and one for the case (each number if you want) Then i was doing a recursive to try to fill it. First I would make a list of all of my empty case, then take the first one and make a list of all the current possible number, scramble them and place one. Then i would continu to the next case. When you can't place a number, you clean the case, return false for exemple and your recursive would go back and try a new number. Repeat until all case are fill. I hope it helps !

Comment: Thats a little too hard for me to understand. Isn't there a way to insert some lines of code to my current script? I created this script with help from my teacher with some psuedo-code parts, but for the backtracking part I havent received one.

Comment: I really don't know how to do it simpler I'm sorry. I would appreciate if you could accept my answer because my code resolved your problem, you can always ask a new question with more details for the backtracking part !

Comment: No problem Shryme;) Im very glad you could help me!